# Use session state for an ApiController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller, session-state

I want to have my own AppContext in my ApiController (MVC4).

Should be something like

```
public class TestController : BaseApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<TestVM> GetAll()
    {
        // the test service is injected with SimpleInjector
        return _testService.GetAll(**base.AppContext**);
    }
}
```

but the ApiController haven't access to the Session.
Are there any solutions to "activate" the Session for specific keys (because I don't want the whole Session)?
Or do you have any other idea (cache or cookie)?

This is the BaseApiController

```
public abstract class BaseApiController: ApiController
{
    public IAppContext AppContext
    {
        get { return SessionState.AppContext; }
    }
}
```

and this is my IAppContext (it will have more properties in the future)

```
public interface IAppContext
{
    IIdentity User { get; }

    /// <summary> Gets the user id. </summary>
    /// <value>The user id.</value>
    int IdUser { get; }
}
```

here the application module which is registered in the web.config

```
public class ApplicationModule : IHttpModule
{
    // ...
    SessionState.AppContext = _appContext.InitializeNew(
        HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, languages);
    // ...
}
```

SessionState class to get the AppContext

```
public class SessionState : BaseSessionVariables
{
    public static IAppContext AppContext
    {
        get { return SessionState.Get<IAppContext>("AppContext"); }
        set { SessionState.Set("AppContext", value); }
    }
}
```

here the BaseSessionVariables class

```
public static HttpSessionState GetSession()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Session;
}

protected static T Get<T>(string key) where T : class
{
    var session = BaseSessionVariables.GetSession();

    if (session == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("No session");
    }
    return (session[key] as T);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the implementation below. It should get you headed in the right direction.

Updated IAppContext - Added Setters

```
public interface IAppContext
{
    IIdentity User { get; set; }

    /// <summary> Gets the user id. </summary>
    /// <value>The user id.</value>
    int IdUser { get; set; }
}
```

Updated Base Controller - Instantiates a new AppContextImplemenation in the OnActionExecuting method

```
public abstract class BaseApiController: ApiController
{
    public IAppContext AppContext {get; set;}

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(
        ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        AppContext = new AppContextImplementation();
    }
}
```

New Class - implements IAppContext and wraps the HttpContext Session.  For testing you can then create an TestAppContextImplementation that doesn't rely on Session but some other in memory storage mechanism.

```
public class AppContextImplementation : IAppContext
{
    public IIdentity User
    { 
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] as IIdentity; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] = value; }
    }

    int IdUser
    { 
        get { return Convert.ToInt32(Session["IdUser"]); }
        set { Session["IdUser"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but there is no overrideable OnActionExecuting in the ApiController

Answer (score -1):

For `ApiControllers`, build yourself a `DelegatingHandler` and push all of your goodies onto `request.Properties`. You can then retrieve them from your request whether you are testing or running live. The benefit is that you then have zero dependency on Session in your Controller.

### MessageHandler

```
public class ContextHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // get the goodies to add onto the request
        var goodies = /* call to goodieGoodieYumYum */


        // add our goodies onto the request
        request.Properties.Add(Constants.RequestKey_Goodies, goodies);

        // pass along to the next handler
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

### Controller Action

```
var goodies = (List<Goodie>)Request.Properties[Constants.RequestKey_Goodies];
```